# SHOW EVERY 7 DAYS FROM PARAMETER

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I want to sort every 7 days from parameter

for example

```
         parameters=
                   @fromDate =  04/May/2019
                   @ToDate   =  01/Jun/2019
```

then the output
  will sort like this:

```
04-11 May 2019...
12-18 May 2019...
19-25 May 2019...
26-01 Jun 2019...
```

thanks all

Comment: Hello - take a read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it will help you get people engaged with your question. Ideally, present some formatted data as you have it, and how you want it. You're asking people to do all the work at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table with dates (dimDate below):

```
    DECLARE @fromDate DATE= '2019-05-04', @ToDate DATE= '2019-06-01', @NbrOfWeeks INT
SELECT @NbrOfWeeks = DATEDIFF(day, @fromdate, @todate) / 7
SELECT WeekNbr, 
       MIN(DateCode) as StartDate, 
       MAX(DateCode) as EndDate
FROM
(
    SELECT NTILE(@NbrOfWeeks) OVER(
           ORDER BY DateCode ASC) AS WeekNbr, 
           DateCode
    FROM dimDate
    WHERE DateCode BETWEEN @fromDate AND @ToDate
) m
GROUP BY WeekNbr;
```

Comment: Out of interest, how come you use `DATEDIFF(day, @fromdate, @todate) / 7`, instead of `DATEDIFF(week, @fromdate, @todate)`

Comment: I was under the impression you wanted 7 day date ranges and not weeks. But use weeks if you want to. But the result will not be the same in all cases

Comment: Not my question, was just curious was all

Comment: If you change the year in the enddate to 2021 and compare the result you'll probably have a difference between the two options, depending on your settings